# Selenium Find Element by xpath using value as well

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to check to see if buttons are present on a page. The number of buttons varies depending on the type of account that logs in. The code below returns true, so I know that the xpath is working.

```
Boolean WorkspacePresent = driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/section[1]/input[1]")).isEnabled();
```

However, I need to make sure that the value is also included, since this just checks how many buttons are there. If I wanted to check for a "Workspace" button, could I still use Find By Xpath?

Comment: Please[Edit] Your question and provide more information like HTML of the page and element you are looking for?

Comment: If you are using java then use following code to get number of elements : `int numberofelements=driver2.findElements(By.xpath("xpath to identify desire element")).size();`

Comment: The problem is that the number of elements will change depending on the login, and the elements will vary. For example, the buttons are workspace, testworkspace, metrics, and admin. If all of the buttons are there, "admin" will be input[4], but if the metrics button isn't there, the admin button will be "input[3]".

Let me know if I'm not doing a good job explaining

Comment: You need post relevant html to get better response from community.

Comment: That isn't really possible. I will try and rephrase my question.

"I want to verify that a button is present on a webpage. The relative Xpath is:

//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/section[1]/input[1]

The button name is "Workspacebutton" and the button value is "Workspace".

Is there a way that I can use findby Xpath to reference the button name or value?

Comment: Instead of using "input[1]" at the end, is it possible to use the button value or name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify the `Workspacebutton` button use following `xpath`.Similar way you can identify other button.

```
driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Workspacebutton' and value='Workspace']"))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much